# What is this called in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, function

I am new to Jquery / Js development. I have seen below code block in an sample JS file downloaded from internet.

```
(function($, undefined) {
...
})(window.jQuery);
```

Can anyone please explain what this code block is all about? I mean please interpret this code block.

Thanks in advance,
BalaGurusamy

Comment: Don't ask questions twice plz.

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Getting_Started

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLonowski for the quick response. Now I understood this stuff of IIFE.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE). The outer parentheses turn the function into an expression instead of a declaration, and the 2nd pair actually invoke it.

The anonymous function accepts 2 arguments, `$` and `undefined`, and you pass in one argument, a reference to the jQuery object. So inside the anonymous function `$` will refer to `jQuery` and since no 2nd argument was provided `undefined` will contain the `undefined` value (which can be important since `undefined` could have been overwritten elsewhere in the script).